# session value is not stored properly

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, express-session

I am using express-session and express-mysql-session in my app to generate sessions and store them in mysql database. Sessions are stored in a table called sessions.

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

const connection = {
  host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
  port: process.env.MYSQL_PORT,
  user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
  password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
};

const sessionStore = new MySQLStore(connection);

module.exports = app => {
  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use(
    session({
      name: 'sessID',
      secret: 'someSecret',
      resave: false,
      store: sessionStore,
      saveUninitialized: true,
    })
  );
```

Sessions are stored in table but the value of it is not as same as the session value in client-side or console.
Example: decoded value in client-side and console is `s:fiNdSdb2_K6qUB_j3OAqhGLEXdWpZkK4.eKUawMNIv7ZtXSweWyIEpfAUnfRd6/rPWr+PsjuGCVQ`, However the value that is stored is `fiNdSdb2_K6qUB_j3OAqhGLEXdWpZkK4`. It's not complete, I have no idea what is happening.

SHOW CREATE TABLE sessions:

```
sessions    CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
`session_id` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin 
 NOT NULL,
 `expires` int unsigned NOT NULL,
 `data` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin,
 PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Comment: Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE sessions` and post the result [into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67976936/edit)

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, this is my first time seeing this but it seems like my request for the `SHOW CREATE TABLE sessions` is actually unnecessary. I've just [read the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-mysql-session) and I can see the table was created by module. May I know how did you know the stored is incomplete? Did you check by running a query in a MySQL tool (e.g. MySQL Workbench or SQLyog)?

Comment: @FaNo_FN Never mind. I wanted to validate user input so I decided to store errors in data column (in case of errors). Thus, I need to match request's session value with session_id in database. I ran query to see the session_id and tried to match with client -side session value, but It's not same, I think it might be of the ```express-mysql-session```. If it is not gonna work, I must use another module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value that's stored on the client-side cookie consists of two parts:

1. The actual session ID (`fiNdSdb2_K6qUB_j3OAqhGLEXdWpZkK4` in your example)
2. A server-generated HMAC signature of the session ID `eKUawMNIv7ZtXSweWyIEpfAUnfRd6/rPWr+PsjuGCVQ`. This is to ensure session ID integrity and does not need to be stored in the database. It's generated on the server-side by `express-session` (which uses [`node-cookie-signature` package](https://github.com/tj/node-cookie-signature) internally) and using the passed `secret` parameter.

So the second part of the cookie name (after the dot) is used by `express-session` to verify the first part and is stripped away afterward.